# a question that has disappeared completely?

Tags: discussion

and a new one appeared of similar content https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53380/inteaction-of-high-energy-particles .

No edits evident.

It was there two hours ago and had a -2 when I added a comment. Usually because of my high reputation I can see the deleted posts off colored. This has completely disappeared.

Whats up?puzzled.

Answer (score 3):

He deleted the question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53368/interaction-of-high-energy-particles-with-matter (10k+ only, should be visible to you), and then he re-posted it.

Comment: thanks, I had not realized that my comment ( activity list) would disappear when the question was deleted and I tried to find the first one that way.

Comment: @annav You could also have found it on the recently deleted list. Use the "tools" menu at the top (which may mean using the "review" menu and switching to the "tools" view) and goto the "deleted" tab.

Comment: @dmckee Tried it but it does not appear for me .There is the recently deleted answer turned to comment of Ibex only.

Comment: @annav *::boggle::* You're right. Now I recall that self-deletes don't appear there. Moderators can find it in the poster's profile, but I'm not sure there *is* a way for a user (even with high rep) to find it.

Comment: @dmckee well, as long it is not Alzheimer's on my part it is OK :)

Comment: @anna unfortunately the software makes it pretty hard to look for deleted questions unless you are a moderator. Mods see deleted questions (and comments if we choose to) on a user profile, and can see deleted stuff in search results if we choose to. But 10k users only have access to the `/tools`  tab, which only talks about recently deleted/undeleted stuff. I guess this is by design.